# Magento 2.4.2-p1 Indexing issue

Tags: magento, indexing

Hi We have migrated our store from **Magento 2.2.5** to **Magento 2.4.1-p1**. We are facing issues with Indexing its taking too long to complete **Category Products index** is taking 2 to 3 hours to complete. Previously in Magento 2.2.5 it was taking just 15 minutes to complete. Currently the search engine is Elastic Search [image: catalog search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Maria DB 10.4 there's an issue with Magento indexing. You need to change following setting under default MariaDB configuration.

```
optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'

optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
```

Its also specified in Magento [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/configuration.html).

> Reindexing on MariaDB 10.4 takes more time compared to other MariaDB
> or MySQL versions. As a workaround, we suggest modifying the default
> MariaDB configuration and setting the following parameters:
>
> optimizer_switch='rowid_filter=off'

> optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1